# Can multiple fragments share a single XML layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have multiple fragments that share the same layout which is a `RecyclerView` inside a `LinearLayout`. In the past, I had files like:

`fragment_one.xml`
`fragment_two.xml`
`fragment_three.xml`
`fragment_four.xml`

Though, I am currently questioning if it is better, to use a single layout named, for example, `fragment_generic`. Is this a good or bad idea?

Thanks.

Comment: `Is this a good or bad idea?` depends your requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually depends on your use case. If you have like 5 fragments which have the same layout i.e a single recyclerview list. It is better to use a single layout for all the purposes. That makes the application really compact.

Later, when some changes come into place and you want to add item , let's suppose a fab icon, then create a new layout and use it for the changed fragment only.

So about your question, yes it would be the best idea to use the same layout for these 4 fragments.

Comment: Thanks @emilpmp. I have another question. I am trying to adapt to a naming convention for my layouts. Is `fragment_generic.xml` a good or bad one?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If its an activity, we would name it activity_x.xml and it its a fragment, we would name it fragment_x.xml. The whole idea is to identify the layouts easily when listed out.

Comment: I meant the `generic` part. Thanks again for the information. Sadly, I do not have the permission to upvote, yet.

Comment: About the generic part,  it should be the name of the fragment. If the name of your fragment is HomeFragment, then the name of the layout would be fragment_home_fragment.xml